# absolutely no response php exit technique?

Tags: php, httpresponse, exit, bandwidth

The docs I read don't seem clear on this issue.

When calling `exit()` with no arguments, does the server still send something back to the client?

If so, is there an alternative or way to keep anything from being sent to the client on exit?

Comment: The headers will still be sent.  Why do you not want to send anything?

Comment: It will send an empty HTTP body, if you did not output anything else. The webserver will still send a HTTP 200 status code, unless you manage to `kill` that parent process.

Comment: @ExplosionPills for my site, when using the slider for dynamic pagination, jQuery will send tons of requests to the server.  I can abort the AJAX request both server and client, but I want all communication between client and server to also stop once aborted by one side or the other.  my bandwidth spikes during these slides.  i want to prevent that

Comment: I'd fix your script first.

Comment: It sounds like you probably don't want jQuery to send tons of requests...

Comment: @ceejayoz What needs fixing?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I want the dynamic pagination to happen quickly.  I need the requests.  I don't need any communication after abortion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exit` is basically the same as reaching the end of the file. Anything that has already been sent will be received by the browsers, and any output buffers will be processed and also sent.

You can force an empty response by include `ob_start()` as your first line of code, and using this function:

```
function exitEmpty() {
    while(ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
    exit;
}
```

However the headers will still be sent. This just empties the response body.

Comment: That's much better!  Thank-you!  I take it you believe there is no way to cancel the response headers?

Comment: Not really. The browser sends the request and needs some kind of response.

Comment: Does it need it if i've aborted client-side as well?  Won't javascript just roll over the missing response headers, or will some sort of memory leak build?

Answer (score 0):

`exit()` will still send headers, if they haven't already been sent, but otherwise it will send nothing else.

Comment: Not exactly true. If you `echo`ed/`print`ed/etc anything before the `exit()` command it will still get sent to the browser along with headers.

Comment: True, but I thought he was only talking about sending the `exit()` command itself.